# How Do Service Connections Work For On-Prem Agents Connecting To On-Prem Services?

Tags: azure-devops

This question is purposefully general because I'm trying to understand things more from an architectural perspective, because that will impact which group I need to contact. My team is using Azure DevOps (cloud) with on-prem build agents. The agents connect to ADO via a proxy.

We use several tools in-house provided by vendors with ADO plugins in the Marketplace that require us to set up service connections. Because the services are installed on-prem, the endpoints we enter are not available via the Web (e.g. https://vendor-product.my-company.com).

If I log into the build machine and open up IE, I am able to connect to the service endpoint URL. However, whenever I try to run a task from ADO, it fails with some kind of connection-related issue ("The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send", "Task ended with an exception: Error: read ECONNRESET", etc.).

The way I thought it worked, all the work takes place on the build machine itself, so the calls would be going from my-build-server.my-company.com to https://vendor-product.my-company.com. Those error messages though make me wonder if the connection is actually coming from https://dev.azure.com.

So the questions I have are:

1. For situations like this, is the connection to a service endpoint going to be seen as coming from my on-prem build agent, or from ADO (or does it vary based on how the vendor writes their plugin)?
2. If the answer to #1 is "it varies", is there any way for me to tell just from the plugin itself without having to contact the vendor? (In my experience some of the vendor reps don't understand how the cloud works.)
   *and/or*
3. Because my build agent was configured to use a proxy when I set it up, is it going to use that proxy for **all** connections, even internal ones? I think I can set up a proxy bypass list for the agents but I presently only have read access to the build box. I can request temporary elevated access but I'd need some level of confidence that's what the issue is.

Hope I explained the situation clearly, thanks in advance for any insight.